# random generating numbers in Bubble Sort

Tags: python, random, bubble-sort

Here is my question I would like to not use numbers that I use but rather that I can put in random numbers ranging from 0 to 50 and then the list can use bubble method to sort it but I can understand how I can use the randomly generated numbers in here

```
def bubbleSort(array):

  for i in range(len(array)):
    data = [8, 45, 0, 11, 6]
    swapped = False

    for j in range(0, len(array) - i - 1):

      if array[j] > array[j + 1]:

        # swapping occurs if elements
        # are not in the intended order
        temp = array[j]
        array[j] = array[j+1]
        array[j+1] = temp

        swapped = True

    if not swapped:
      break
```

Comment: "how I can use the randomly generated numbers in here" You seem to know how to (bubble-)sort is, but  should you real question no be: "How can I generate a list of random values?" (otherwise this question does not make much sense, and need clarification)

Comment: Just for future questions after the three back quotes, you can type the languages name - in this case `python` (`py` is valid too), for syntax highlighting - just makes it a bit easier to read.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must call your function with the list you want to sort, i.e. with the function:

```
def bubble_sort(lst):
    n = len(lst)
    for i in range(n - 1):
        swapped = False

        for j in range(0, n - i - 1):
            if lst[j] > lst[j + 1]:
                swapped = True
                lst[j], lst[j+1] = lst[j+1], lst[j]

        if not swapped:
            return
```

You'll call it like this:

```
data = [8, 45, 0, 11, 6]
bubble_sort(data)
print(data)   # should now be sorted
```

(bubble sort, sorts the list in-place)